I have successfully installed the pypdf2 but not able to import it into my python file
I have successfully installed the pypdf2 module but while importing it, i am getting that this module is missing.
I tried importing using
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

But its not working
what are the various solutions to this problem?

Check your path

Use pip list | grep <module_name_you_want_to_check> to check if the module is installed
In your case that would be
pip list | grep PyPDF2

If the problem persists you can try uninstalling with
pip uninstall <module name> and then reinstall the module.
